# Interpretation of a three-level contrast in a linear mixed-effect model in R

Tags: r, interpretation, lme4-nlme, contrasts

I have a linear mixed effect model in R where my fixed effect consists of three levels: `Yes`, `No` and `Maybe`

I have two research questions regarding these levels and my dependent variable:

1. Is `Yes` smaller than `No` ?
2. Where does `Maybe` stand in relation to `Yes` and `No` (closer to which)?

I specified centered contrast for my levels:

```
        -Yes+No  -Maybe+Yes&No
Maybe     0.0    -0.6666667
No        0.5     0.3333333
yes      -0.5     0.3333333
```

The output of the linear mixed effect model (the fixed effects part) is:

```
Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std.  Error   t value
(Intercept)                  -2.24393    0.09051 -24.791
Grammaticallity-Yes+No       -0.82596    0.17168  -4.811
Grammaticallity-Maybe+Yes&No -0.73459    0.11753  -6.250
```

From this I can clearly see that the response to `Yes` is less negative than the response to `No` by -0.8 in the scale of my dependent variable.

My doubt is how to interpret the second contrast. I know by looking at bar graphs that the response to `Maybe` is the less negative of the three responses:

[image]

However, from the output I would interpret the response to `Maybe` is 0.7 more negative in the scale of my dependent variable than the average of the responses to `Yes` and `No`. However, this is clearly not the case, as the response to `Maybe` is more positive (less negative) than the responses to `Yes` and `No`.

I would appreciate any help to interpret and properly report the estimate of the second contrast comparing `Maybe` to the average of `Yes` and `No`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If those are your research questions, why not just compare the %ages using, for instance, t tests?

Comment: @PeterFlom I am not comparing ages, and the reason why I don't use a t-test is because I want to include other factors as random intercepts and random slopes.

Comment: First, I said %ages (which is short for percentages, not ages; sorry for any confusion). But if you want to include random intercepts and slopes, yourn your research questions are improperly stated.

Comment: @PeterFlom I didn't think specifying all my random intercepts and slopes would be relevant for the specific question I have about three-level contrasts. I just want to know what the estimate of the second contrast is telling in regarding the difference between the `Maybe` level and the `Yes` and `No` levels together.

Comment: Right now, your research questions don't specify an independent variable.  So, what are you modeling?

Comment: Microvolts in an ERP component as a function of a variable called `Grammaticality` which has three levels, `Yes`, `No` and `Maybe`. The estimate for the first contrast tells me the average response (calculated in the estimate of the intercept) has a slope of -0.82 microvolts when going from `Yes` to `No`. That is, `No` is more negative by -0.82 microvolts than `Yes`. The second contrast of `Grammaticality` has the level `Maybe` compared to the average of `Yes` and `No`. This is the estimate I need help interpreting.